# UCI engine command white giving the same move

Tags: analysis, engines, stockfish, uci

I need help from someone who knows about UCI engines. I am giving the command by double clicking on stockfishengine.exe and manually entering commands.
I wanted to play white and I am running arena to play as computer (black).

I entered the following pgns in sequence:
e2e4, e7e5 (arena)... , e2e4

```
Commands entered:
uci
...
ucinewgame
...
position startpos
...
go infinite
...logs here...
stop
bestmove e2e4 ponder
------------
Arena GUI using stockfish engine made move : e7e5
------------
position startpos e2e4 e7e5
go infinite
...
logs here
...
stop
bestmove e2e4 ponder e7e5
```

As you can see above its still giving me e2e4 it should have suggested other moves for white instead of giving me the same best move. Can anyone help me on this? Thanks

Update:

Its still giving me the same best move. Maybe their are other things that I have to set before issuing position startpos ... command?

[image]

[image]

Comment: To debug on Stockfish console, type "d". Try it.

Comment: You are missing moves in the startpos command in your edited. Please look carefully how I typed.

Comment: oppss didn't see that thanks. Its working now. I'll try more moves and see if it will give me something else.

Comment: Its now working student_T couldn't have done it without you. Now just a quick question, I wanted to start a new post but it seems like a waste. Is there a command to tell stockfish to read a .pgn file?

Comment: According to the rule of the website, I should only answer a question per post. Also, please consider accepting my answer if you think it's helpful.

Comment: Ok i'll do another post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow my instructions in the screenshot.

[image]

[image]

Comment: hi again Student_T, please check my update. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You must send a new position to the engine after each move. There are two main ways to send the new position, which are to send a FEN, or to send the moves themselves.

1. `position fen rnbqkbnr/pppp1ppp/8/4p3/4P3/8/PPPP1PPP/RNBQKBNR b KQkq - 0 2`
2. `position startpos moves e2e4 e7e5`